# 'Add new page' on production doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, refinerycms

The app works fine in local , but when i open the refinery app in production - home page is missing . I shifted my migration but still no help . Surprisingly , the contact , blog and forem page show up minus the css . All the errors i get to see are a banner written - Sorry , something must have gone wrong or you must have mistyped the address .

Also i had included bootstrap and bootstrap responsive to my project , all the css files are getting compiled .

Following error i took out from the terminal

```
    Started GET "/assets/refinery/application.css.scss" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-21 14:41:41 +0530
Served asset /refinery/application.css.scss - 404 Not Found (25ms)
Processing by Refinery::PagesController#show as 
  Parameters: {"path"=>"assets/refinery/application.css", "locale"=>:en}
  Rendered public/404.html (0.1ms)
Filter chain halted as :find_page rendered or redirected
Completed 404 Not Found in 29ms (Views: 9.6ms | ActiveRecord: 10.1ms)
Started GET "/assets/refinery/about.css.scss" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-21 14:41:41 +0530
Served asset /refinery/about.css.scss - 404 Not Found (21ms)
Processing by Refinery::PagesController#show as 
  Parameters: {"path"=>"assets/refinery/about.css", "locale"=>:en}
  Rendered public/404.html (0.1ms)
Filter chain halted as :find_page rendered or redirected
Completed 404 Not Found in 31ms (Views: 16.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

Please help , thanx in advance :)

Comment: just for testing, apply `true` for property `config.serve_static_assets` in your `config/environments/production.rb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming due to bootstrap , 
Had to rename my application.css -> application.css.scss

Also did the @imports bootstrap
Make sure you have require 'bootstrap' in config